# Unity WebCamTexture video lags in lowlight conditions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video, webcam, exposure

I have made a simple video streaming application in unity.I use the device Webcam through unity's WebCamTexture class. I have a RawImage in my canvas on which i render the WebCam live feed as follows:

```
public RawImage image;                 
private WebCamTexture liveRec;


void Start () {

    WebCamDevice[] camDevices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    liveRec = new WebCamTexture(camDevices[camDevices.Length - 1].name);
    liveRec.requestedHeight = 1;                
    liveRec.requestedWidth = 1;              // lowest quality
    liveRec.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
    liveRec.Play();
    image.texture = liveRec;

              }
```

Everything is working perfectly, the video runs smooth, but only in good lighting conditions.When my room becomes dark(low lighting conditions) the video becomes very laggy(seems to be around 25fps).I thought it is a problem in my application, but when i accessed the WebCam through the Windows control panel, there it was also lagging but then i saw an option there "ExposureCompensation" i don't know what it is but when i lowered it the video became darker but smooth again(see image)[image].Now what can i do about this in my application, how to access and lower this parameter(C#).

THINGS I HAVE TRIED:

> > I have used about every shader on my rawimage although some seem to darken the texture but the lag persists
> >
> > I have used NatCam but it doesn't provide full functionality in windows(Falls back to unity's implementation "Webcamtexture")
> >
> > Have read other questions that use DirectShow api which seems to be incredibly difficult to me, and have no idea whether it will work with unity or not

Please help me i will be much obliged! (and treat me as a student not as a professional)

EDIT:  This is not a WebCam Specific problem, i have tested the same application on 2 laptops with their own integrated cameras, the lag persists in low lighting conditions.

Comment: I have few questions...How exactly do you know that the video is 25fps? Also, are you doing anything else in your code? Does this happen if you just have the code in your `Start` function without any other code running in a coroutine or in the `Update` function.

Comment: i was just speculating i don't have any code to check it.I am sorry i will remove those lines

Comment: @Programmer I just have this code in the start function, no other code anywhere else, and no other script this is the only script.

Comment: And just now i have checked that even the software that came with the webcam, can't run the video smooth in low light conditions without lowering the exposure.

Comment: What happens when you pass width and height when creating the WebCamTexture. `liveRec = new WebCamTexture(camDevices[camDevices.Length - 1].name,500,500);`

Comment: Nothing changes :(, still lagging

Comment: The only thing that changes is the camera resolution, previously (160W x 120H) and now (640W x 480H)